# Add node to existing resource file C#

Tags: c#, resources

I have an issue when i try to attach a node to a resource file.
I start with deleting the file:
- *.resx and create a new one with:
- File.Create(*.resx).Close();

I have an iterative method that should write a Node in that file, but the result is a resource file containing only the last node. I searched this forum for a solution and found that the solution have to be that i read in elements/nodes in the file (empty from start) and then write them again, with my new node at the end. Then i do this iterative. Its not efficient at all but since it doesn't `matter in this case i can live with that. However i get stuck with issues that the file is already open in an other process. I did some changes and now i get an issue that i cant add a Node that is already added. Need some help. Here is my code:

```
private void WriteToResxFile(List<CompleteString> listStrings)
    {
        ResXResourceWriter writer;
        ResXResourceReader reader;
        IDictionaryEnumerator readerNode;
        ResXDataNode node;
        FileInfo fileInfo;
        Hashtable resourceEntries;
        System.ComponentModel.Design.ITypeResolutionService typeres;
        string text;

        RemoveExistingResxFiles();

        foreach (Language lang in languages)    
        {
            foreach (ResourceFile file in resourcefilesPaths)
            {
                fileInfo = new FileInfo(file.mPath);
                fileInfo.IsReadOnly = false;
                reader = new ResXResourceReader(file.mPath);

                reader.UseResXDataNodes = true;
                fileInfo.IsReadOnly = false;
                typeres = null;

                foreach (CompleteString completeString in listStrings)
                {
                    if (completeString.mFileName.Equals(file.mResxName))
                    {
                        int index = file.mPath.IndexOf(".");
                        if (lang.mResx.Equals(file.mPath.Substring(index)))
                        {
                            writer = new ResXResourceWriter(file.mPath);
                            if (reader != null && fileInfo.Length != 0)
                            {
                                foreach (DictionaryEntry d in reader)
                                {
                                    //Read from file:
                                    resourceEntries = new Hashtable(); 
                                    string val = "";
                                    if (d.Value == null)
                                        resourceEntries.Add(d.Key.ToString(), "");
                                    else
                                    {
                                        val = ((ResXDataNode)d.Value).GetValue(typeres).ToString();
                                        resourceEntries.Add(d.Key.ToString(), val);

                                    }

                                    //Write (with read to keep xml file order)
                                    ResXDataNode dataNode = (ResXDataNode)d.Value;

                                    writer.AddResource(dataNode);

                                }
                                reader.Close();
                            }
                            text = CorrectStringDependedOnLangauge(completeString, lang);
                            node = new ResXDataNode(completeString.mStringName, text);
                            node.Comment = completeString.mStringType;
                            fileInfo.IsReadOnly = false;
                            writer.AddResource(node);
                            writer.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }                  

            }
        }
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
           foreach (Language lang in languages)    
        {
            foreach (ResourceFile file in resourcefilesPaths)
            {
                fileInfo = new FileInfo(file.mPath);
                fileInfo.IsReadOnly = false;
                fileInfo.IsReadOnly = false;
                typeres = null;

                foreach (CompleteString completeString in listStrings)
                {
                    if (completeString.mFileName.Equals(file.mResxName))
                    {
                        int index = file.mPath.IndexOf(".");
                        if (lang.mResx.Equals(file.mPath.Substring(index)))
                        {
                            reader = new ResXResourceReader(file.mPath);
                            reader.UseResXDataNodes = true;
                            writer = new ResXResourceWriter(file.mPath);
                            if (reader != null && fileInfo.Length != 0)
                            {    
                                foreach (DictionaryEntry d in reader)
                                {
                                    resourceEntries = new Hashtable(); 
                                    string val = "";
                                    if (d.Value == null)
                                        resourceEntries.Add(d.Key.ToString(), "");
                                    else
                                    {
                                        val = ((ResXDataNode)d.Value).GetValue(typeres).ToString();
                                        resourceEntries.Add(d.Key.ToString(), val);

                                    }
                                    ResXDataNode dataNode = (ResXDataNode)d.Value;
                                    writer.AddResource(dataNode);
                                }          
                            }
                            reader.Close();
                            text = CorrectStringDependedOnLangauge(completeString, lang);
                            node = new ResXDataNode(completeString.mStringName, text);
                            node.Comment = completeString.mStringType;
                            fileInfo.IsReadOnly = false;
                            writer.AddResource(node);
                            writer.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }  
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems to me you'd better create the writer *outside* of the foreach loop.  You don't want to create a .resx file for each individual CompleteString.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by change where the .resx file where open closed. The script can now write to different .resx files etc .resx, .da-DE.resx depending on the information in CompleteStrings. However, it is not time effective since when jumping between .resx files i have to clear the file I current like to write to by first read in all data and then open the writer, write back all data and append the new string. But for me isn't this an issue.